# How do we use null safety plugin and non null safety plugin in same project flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety, searchable-dropdown

Recently I have migrated my project to null safety. I need to use one non null safety plugin into it. How is it possible to mix non-null safety plugin with null safety plugin?